# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous when using .apply(lambda)

Tags: pandas

I'm getting value error from this code, which I want to label True if the 'id' is found in my_array

```
df['exist'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: True if df['id'].isin(my_array) else False)
```

I understood the value error may be caused by using 'and', 'or' in the code instead of '&', '|'. However, I'm not using any of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['id'].isin(my_array)` itself is a series, and `if df['id'].isin(my_array)` will throw that error because Python doesn't know how to evaluate a series as a single `True/False`.

Just use `isin` without any `apply`:

```
df['exist'] = df['id'].isin(my_array)
```

Comment: what if i want to label data with 1,0 instead of True False, i guess in that situation i need to use a function ?

Comment: @Osca chain that with `.astype(int)`: `df['exist'] = df['id'].isin(my_array).astype(int)`